# Getting terms and only evaluate specific parts of a series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, output-formatting, series-expansion, hold

How to write the first five terms of this series in the following form by MMA code?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot(2 n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \cdots \cdot 2 n}= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 4}+\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6}+\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8}+\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot 10}$

I tried to write code with `HoldForm`, but I couldn't get the result.

For example,

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+n}{1+n^{2}}$

```
Sum[(HoldForm[(1 + #1)/(1 + #1^2)] & )[i], {i, 1, 5}]
```

> $\frac{1+1}{1+1^{2}}+\frac{1+2}{1+2^{2}}+\frac{1+3}{1+3^{2}}+\frac{1+4}{1+4^{2}}+\frac{1+5}{1+5^{2}}$

Or,

```
Total[Apply[HoldForm[#1/#2] & , 
  Table[{1 + i, 1 + i^2}, {i, 1, 5}], {1}]]
```

> $\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4}{10}+\frac{5}{17}+\frac{6}{26}$

**Update: Some other questions**

How to get the results in the following form?

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot(2 n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \cdots \cdot 2 n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{5}{16}+\frac{35}{128}+\frac{63}{256}$
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{5^{n}}=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{5^{2}}+\frac{1}{5^{3}}-\frac{1}{5^{4}}+\frac{1}{5^{5}}=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{25}+\frac{1}{125}-\frac{1}{625}+\frac{1}{3125}$
3. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+n}{1+n^{2}}= 1+\frac{3}{5}+\frac{2}{5}+\frac{5}{17}+\frac{3}{13}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
times[{i_}] := i
times[{i__}] := Inactive[Times][i]

Sum[times@Table[2 i - 1, {i, n}]/times@Table[2 i, {i, n}], {n, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you prefer `HoldForm`:

```
times[{i_}] := i
times[{i__}] := HoldForm@Times[##] &[i]

Sum[times@Table[2 i - 1, {i, n}]/times@Table[2 i, {i, n}], {n, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you prefer `·`, then you don't need any evaluation control, just use `CenterDot`:

```
times[{i_}] := i
times[{i__}] := CenterDot[i]

Sum[times@Table[2 i - 1, {i, n}]/times@Table[2 i, {i, n}], {n, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your answer is great! Thank you!

Comment: One more question. How to simplify each item to get this result: =1/2+3/8+5/16+35/128+63/256

Comment: I just updated my questions and have a few more questions. Thank you very much!

Comment: @lotus2019 If you've understood my code, then you should be able to solve it yourself. What have you tried?

Comment: OK, thank you. I am learning MMA by solving math problems with MMA. I really don't understand some of the code, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: @lotus2019 If you're having difficulty in understanding certain part of the answer, check the document or ask the answerer in the comment. Keep asking questions without understanding the obtained answer won't help you learning MMA.

Comment: Interesting for learning more : what to tell about two expressions ?

`times[{i_}] := i`

`times[{i__}] := Inactive[Times][i]`

Comment: @janhardo I'm not sure if I've understood your question. Are you having difficulty with `i_` and `i__`? If so, the pattern `i_` matches only one argument so the first function definition handles cases like `times[{1}]`, the pattern `i__` matches one or more arguments so it handles cases like `times[{3, 5}]`. To learn this in a more systematic way, read e.g. 1. https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/41-more-about-patterns.html 2. https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/chapterNode5.html If you still have difficulty in understanding, feel free to ask.

Comment: @ xzczd, its only that a step by step explanation how you construct this , that it can be quick understood,otherwise its impossible to understand this.
I made this a startingpoint to arrive at the same series examples? 
`numerator = Sum[Table[2*i - 1, {i, n}], {n, 5}]`   and   `denumerator = Sum[Table[2*i, {i, n}], {n, 5}]`

Comment: @ xcczd , Let me ask one question about he pattern definition : `times[{i_}] := i` , those { } were they are standing for ?

Comment: @janhardo I really suggest you to learn pattern matching in a more systematic way by reading the materials in my last comment. As to your specific example, it's all because the **pattern** of the expression should match, just execute `times[1]` and `times[{1}]` and observe the output, and think about why you've obtained these outputs.

Comment: @ xcczd i executed  `times[1]` and `times[{1}]`  and noticed the  one is placed between brackets. Now to `times[{i_}] := i` ,its a function definition  ( it is confusing the distinction between functional programming versus pattren matching )

Comment: @janhardo It's **not** _functional programming versus pattren matching_. `times[{i_}] := i` is a function definition based on pattern-matching. Do notice the left hand side of a function is not limited to things like `f[x_]` or `g[x_, y_, z_]`, you can use almost any expression (as long as it's valid) as the left hand side to define a function.

Comment: @xccd ,  I had gotten that idea too that this function notation is based on pattern recognition
I just can't figure out why the argument of the function has to be specially enclosed in brackets

Comment: @janhardo Now execute `Table[2 i - 1, {i, 1}]` and observe the output.

Comment: @xccd, its a list as output ,  { list } or nested etc

Comment: @janhardo Now you should understand why I define `times` like this.

Comment: @xcczd, Yes, i see it now i think : Table[2 i - 1, {i, 1}] == {1} acts for 1 and some more values of n as argument for the times function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134815/discussion-between-xzczd-and-janhardo).